# How can I bind a value from a datepicker to an angular2 model?

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, datepicker

I develop an app with angular2 and have to use a datepicker for firefox ([other browsers have in inbrowser datepicker](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)). The problem is by using a datepicker I loose the two way binding of my model. It doesn't matter if I use [pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday), [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or other javascript datepickers. The behaviour is the same.

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    name="datum" 
    class="datepicker" 
    [(ngModel)]="datum" 
/>
```

Other way, same result

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    name="datum" 
    class="datepicker" 
    [value]="datum" 
    (input)="datum = $event.target.value" 
/>
```

jQuery UI datepicker fallback for firefox

```
(function() {
    var elem = document.createElement('input');
    elem.setAttribute('type', 'date');

    if ( elem.type === 'text' ) {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(); 
    }
})();
```

If I pick a date it only appears in the input field, but doesn't exists as value in the model <strike>(btw, [I tried a plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/rwYWHwHtflJfhNejRdiB/) but it failed because of the 'banana in a box' syntax [I can't bring jQuery to work in it])</strike>.

Checkout [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/9HRCazsmNvMzAhW0Evub/) to see the problem live (in firefox).

I know, this is a very specific problem, but maybe someone had it before and found a solution. And if this one can post it here this would make me very happy.

Comment: I think you might be binding to the wrong event in your second example. I don't remember which one it is but have you tried `(change)="datum = $event"` or `(valueChange)="datum = $event"`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for reply. Your suggestions work only when datepicker is off.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This works for me...ngModel is binding properly.
 **you have not imported formsModule in your module.**

Comment: Thanks for reply and your hint to create a correct plunker example.

Answer (score 1):

you can add change event.

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    name="datum" 
    class="datepicker" 
    [ngModel]="datum" 
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" 
/>


onChange(event : any){
  // add your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunatly it doesn't work. I tried `(change)="..."` ,too, without luck. It's tricky.